# Evaluation of a certain Gaussian integral

Tags: probability, integration, gaussian-integral

I wish to prove that for any $a\in\mathbb R$
$$
\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{-A}^A \frac{e^{-x^2/2-(a+x)^2/2}(a+2x)}{e^{-x^2/2}+e^{-(a+x)^2/2}}dx = 0.
$$

I have verified the above equality for multiple $a\in\mathbb R$ values using Monte Carlo, but don't know how to prove it rigorously. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Mathematica cannot evaluate the indefinite integral via symbolic computation :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a shift of the variable

$$
I=\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{-A+a/2}^{A+a/2} \frac{e^{-(x-a/2)^2/2-(a/2+x)^2/2}\,x}{e^{-(x-a/2)^2/2}+e^{-(a/2+x)^2/2}}dx = 0.
$$

and the integrand is odd.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot you can offset by $a/2$ :)